# Java: Creating a class using array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a class ExchangeRates which describes exchange rates (a currency is represented as a String (for instance ”USD”) and a number (for instance 5.49)). ExhangeRates must have a method to set and get rates for different currencies. If v is an object of the class ExhangeRates, the following method calls must be possible:

- `v.setRate(”USD”, 5.49)`: sets the rate for the currency ”USD” to 5.49. If the currency ”USD” doesn't already exist, it must be added. If it exists, it must be changed to the new rate.
- `x = v.getRate(”GBP”)`: sets x as the rate for the currency ”GBP”. If the currency doesn't exist, return 0.
- `x = v.amountOfRates()`: sets x as amount of exchange rates that exists in v.
- `x = v.averageRate()`: sets x as the avergae of all the rates.

How can I create this class using array?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class ExchangeRates {
private String name;
private float[] rate;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public ExchangeRates(String currencyName, float exchangeRate) {
    name = currencyName;
    rate = new float[];
}

public void setExhangeRate (String currencyName, float exchangeRate) {
    name = this.currencyName;
    rate = this.exchangeRate;
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you tried first. Also, Java 7 has a `java.util.Currency` class you might use. What do `amountOfRates` and `averageRate` mean? They don't seem very useful.  Oh, and returning `0` for an error condition would be better done by throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Java data types, but why are you asking about array specifically? This sounds more like a job for a dictionary type.

Comment: One way you could create an instance of your currency class by using an array is to declare a constructor that takes an array.  that array could be a list of currency codes you want your instance to handle.

Comment: What do you think you need an array for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want for each currency to be able to map a number (exchange rate) to currency. Why not just use a Map in the Exchange rate?

```
public class ExchangeRates {
private String name;
private Map<String, Float> rate;

public ExchangeRates(String currencyName) {
    name = currencyName;
    rate = new HashMap<String, Float>();
}

public void setExhangeRate (String currencyName, float exchangeRate) {
    rate.put(currencyNam, exchangeRate)
}

public Float getRate(String currencyName)
{
     return rate.get(currencyName);
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I will be using a HashMap for later, but how would you go about solving the task using array?

Answer (score 0):

One bad version:

```
public class ExchangeRates {

  private String name;
  private String[] names;
  private float[] rates;

  public ExchangeRates( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.names = {};
    this.rates = {};
  }

  public int amountOfRates() {
    return rates.length;
  }

  public float averageRate() {
    float sum = 0;
    for ( float rate : rates )
      sum += rate;
    return sum / rates.length;
  }

  public float getRate( String name ) {
    for ( int i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i -- )
      if ( names[ i ].equals( name ) )
        return rates[ i ];
    return 0;
  }

  public void setRate( String name, float rate ) {
    for ( int i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i -- )
      if ( names[ i ].equals( name ) ) {
        rates[ i ] = rate;
        return;
      }
    names = Array.copyOf( names, names.length + 1 );
    rates = Array.copyOf( rates, rates.length + 1 );
    names[ names.length - 1 ] = name;
    rates[ rates.length - 1 ] = rate;
  }

}
```

Second bad version (a little better wrt. OOP):

```
public class ExchangeRates {

  private static class Rate {
    private String name;
    private float rate;
    Rate( String name, float rate ) {
      this.name = name;
      this.rate = rate;
    }
  }

  private String name;
  private Rate[] rates;

  public ExchangeRates( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rates = {};
  }

  public int amountOfRates() {
    return rates.length;
  }

  public float averageRate() {
    float sum = 0;
    for ( Rate rate : rates )
      sum += rate.rate;
    return sum / rates.length;
  }

  public float getRate( String name ) {
    for ( Rate rate : rates )
       if ( rate.name.equals( name ) )
        return rate.rate;
    return 0;
  }

  public void setRate( String name, float rate ) {
    for ( Rate rate : rates )
      if ( rate.name.equals( name ) ) {
        rate.rate = rate;
        return;
      }
    rates = Array.copyOf( rates, rates.length + 1 );
    rates[ rates.length - 1 ] = new Rate( name, rate );
  }

}
```

You should really use a map.

```
public class ExchangeRates {

  private String name;
  private Map<String,Float> rates;

  public ExchangeRates( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rates = new HashMap<String,Float>();
  }

  public int amountOfRates() {
    return rates.size();
  }

  public float averageRate() {
    float sum = 0;
    for ( Float rate : rates.values() )
      sum += rate;
    return sum / rates.size();
  }

  public float getRate( String name ) {
    Float rate = rates.get( name );
    return rate == null ? 0 : rate.floatValue();
  }

  public void setRate( String name, float rate ) {
    rates.put( name, rate );
  }

}
```